# How Can I listen for a REST-like endpoint in a Graphql resolver?

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, graphql, apollo-server

After successfully integrating  a 3rd party REST Oauth Api, now i am trying to convert the api logic into a graphql query but i'm kind of stuck on how best to architect the query.

From a REST perspective, i have something like this that works 100%

```
  app.get("/auth/redirect", async (req: Request, res:Response) => {
    const code = req.query.code
    const { access_token, account_id } = await getTokens({
      code,
      clientId,
      clientSecret,
    })

    try{
      const result = await axios
      .get(
        `https://api.specificservice.dev/helloworld/id/v1/accounts?accountId=${account_id}`,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
          },
        }
      )

      console.log('Fetching user..', result.data)
      return result.data
    }
    catch (error: any) {
      let message = error.result.data
      console.log(message)
      return message
    }
  })
```

from Graphql, I've got a sketch like this.

```
getPlatform: async (_: any, _args: any, { req }: any) => {
  const clientId = "test"
  const clientSecret = "test"
  const code = req.query.code
  const { access_token, account_id } = await getTokens({
    code,
    clientId,
    clientSecret,
  })
  
  try{
    const result = await axios
    .get(
      `https://api.specificservice.dev/helloworld/id/v1/accounts?accountId=${account_id}`,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
        },
      }
    )
  
    console.log('Fetching user..', result.data)
    return result.data
  }
  catch (error: any) {
    let message = error.result.data
    console.log(message)
    return message
  }
},
```

How can I refactor this to suit what I'm trying to do from the rest endpoint

Comment: args are for ... args ... use/pass args as variables

Comment: what am i passing as an argument??

Comment: you should pass args by query variables - received by args (2nd) resolver argument ... returning data should work ... if matches return type .... where is the problem? args, return? debug attempts?

Comment: please could you go through the post again to try and understand my question? i am trying to convert a rest endpoint to a graphql query.

Comment: query is a client request ... assuming you're trying to define getPlatform as a resolver ... edit your question to explain it more precisely, what the question is about, where you get wrong values/errors